# Java Generics - Unchecked cast from "capture#1 of ?" to "A"

Tags: java, generics, casting, generic-programming

I have 2 warnings:

- Warning 1: `unchecked cast, required: A  found:  capture#1 of ?`
- Warning 2: `unchecked cast, required: A  found:  Congress`

I know that the class is in fact an Event.

Where Event is an Interface and Exhibition and Congress both implement the Event interface.

```
public static <A extends Event> A copy(A event) {
        Class<?> eventType = event.getClass(); // --> Warning 1
        return (A) eventType.getConstructor(eventType).newInstance(event);
    return event;
}
```

The second Warning:

```
public static <A extends Event> A create(EventType type) {
    if(type == EventType.CONGRESS){ 
        return (A) new Congress() // --> Warning 2
    }else(){
        return (A) new Exhibition() // --> Same as warning 2 but for Exibition
    }
}
```

Now the question is: How can i resolve this two warnings without using:

```
@SuppressWarning("unchecked")
```

Comment: For the second example: what would happen if you wrote: `Exhibition e = create(EventType.CONGRESS);`?

Comment: `create` should not be generic (in such form). Type is known at runtime so no reason to use generic here. It should return `Event`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are misusing generics. If the *method* gets to decide what type to return, you should not use generics. Generics are used when the caller decides what type to return.

So `create` should be like this:

```
public static Event create(EventType type) {
    if(type == EventType.CONGRESS){ 
        return new Congress();
    }else {
        return new Exhibition();
    }
}
```

For the first warning, you can do something like this.

```
public static <A extends Event> A copy(A event) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    return (A) event.getClass().getConstructor(event.getClass()).newInstance(event);

}
```

Comment: For the first warning, it still gives the same warning, in the return line, and also, since the T is undefined, it results in a compilation error

Comment: @DiogoSoares I mean `A`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can resolve the first warning by declaring `eventType` as `Class<? extends A>`. This makes the cast to `A` superfluous.</s>

If you cannot change the return type of the first method, there is no option to resolve this compilation issue without resorting to casting. The compilation issue can be resolved by changing the return type of the method to `Event`. If you change the return type to `Event`, you can fully drop the generic parameter:

```
public static Event copy(Event e)
        throws NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalAccessException,
            InstantiationException,
            InvocationTargetException {
    Class<? extends Event> cls = e.getClass();
    return cls.getConstructor(cls).newInstance();
}
```

---

For the second warning, you can also fully drop the generic type of the method:

```
public Event create(EventType type) {
    if (type == EventType.CONGRESS) {
        return new Congress();
    } else {
        return new Exhibition();
    }
}
```

This assumes that `Congress extends Event` and `Exhibition extends Event`.

Comment: I've tried already to resolve the first warning as you said, but the thing is that it gives an compilation error:  incompatible types: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends Event> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends A>

Comment: The problem with that implementation is that it will always return java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make this a static method?

```
public static <A extends Event> A copy(A event) {
        Class<?> eventType = event.getClass(); // --> Warning 1
        return (A) eventType.getConstructor(eventType).newInstance(event);
    return event;
}
```

You have an instance of Event, let the `Event` class be able to create a copy of itself.

```
abstract class Event<E extends Event<E>> {
    public E createCopy(E toCopy);
}
```

with

```
class Exhibition extends Event<Exhibition> {
    // ...
    public Exhibition createCopy() {
        return new Exhibition(this); 
    }
}
```

What you can to get rid of the second warning is adjusting `EventType` to

```
public enum EventType {
    CONGRESS { public Event createEvent() { return new Congress(); }},
    EXHIBITION { public Event createEvent() { return new Exhibition(); }};

    public abstract Event createEvent();
}
```

which will result in

```
public static Event create(EventType type) {
    return type.createEvent();
}
```

If it's really necessary to know the exact type of event that's returned, you should really reconsider the design at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using TypeTags aka ClassTags. Something like:

```
public static <A extends Event> Optional<A> create(Class<A> classTag) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(classTag.newInstance());
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Call it like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional<Exhibition> e = create(Exhibition.class);
    e.ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: This is such a nonsence as in this form he should simply `new Whatever`

Comment: @Antoniossss: you are right in this small context. But we don't know the project in complete. So a generic solution might have its benefits.

Comment: So if you have admited that this answer is worthless as you don't know the context and you have made some assumptions (you have admited that too) feel free to remove that answer.

Comment: My point is that ClassTags avoid unchecked cast warnings. That's all. Just the well known trouble with type erasure.